# Confusion regarding initialization of Swift variables

Tags: ios, swift

Am new to ios development,

I have one basic doubt as they say,

> Each and every instance variable or a property must be initialized in
>   Swift unless it is declared as Optionals

I totally agree the above statement and the two ways are like the below,

```
 var data : String?
```

or

```
var data :String = "abc"
```

but I dont know what like this means ,

`var data :String = String()`

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: i think `String()` just creates a new instance of a string, so its like going `var data :String = ""`, just taking an educated guess here

Comment: thanks for your reply,,,but then what does this means **var globalHud : MBProgressHUD = MBProgressHUD()**

Comment: same thing effectively, `MBProgressHUD()` creates a new instance of a `MBProgressHUD` object and is assigning it to `globalHud`

Comment: its a good question nonetheless but i highly recommend going through the swift documentation ebook.Maybe do 2 hours a day. Things like this should not be bothering a developer unless you don't want to be a developer. Think about how many similar questions you might have. Start studying documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these work in similar way. As you might already know, swift has a feature called Type inference. It will deduce the type of variable by looking @ the assigning value. For example when you say `var data :String = "hello world"`, swift will understand that it is a string variable.

There is also another way to initialise a variable, that is by using initialisers. `var data :String = String()` is a direct example for the same. This line of code will use Init() method defined in `String` to do the initialisation. Check out [Apple documentation on Default Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data :String = String()
```

It creates Empty String
and it is same as

```
var data :String = ""
```

hope you get the answer